# preposition "путем"

Tags: выбор-слова

Which case should be used after the preposition "путем" which means "by means of" ?
could you give couple of examples?
What is the exact meaning? What is the difference between путем and через?

Comment: "Через" has no connection with "путем", do you know any? Your question about the difference between them sounds like "What's the difference between 'under' and 'after'?" Every good dictionary gives you all the information about every preposition, with tons of examples.

Comment: @YellowSky, "через" can also mean "by means of". E. g. "казнь через повешение". In fact, you can use "через" with the accusative case in all of the examples in your answer.

Comment: Please, do not forget to uppercase each sentence.

Comment: @Dima, именно в примерах из моего ответа "через" звучало бы дико.

Comment: @YellowSky, "Мы добьемся решения этой проблемы через референдум." По-моему совсем не дико. :)

Comment: @Dima, почему бы вам тогда не написать полноценный ответ о связях и разнице между "путём" и "через"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preposition `путём` needs Genitive case, and means "with the help of", "by the means of", and it is rather bookish. Examples:

> Мы добьёмся решения этой проблемы **путём референдума**.
>
> В этом случае открытый аукцион в электронной форме проводится **путем повышения** цены контракта.
>
> Физическая терморегуляция осуществляется **путем изменений** отдачи тепла организмом.

Comment: I wonder whether it is actually preposition or a noun? How can we know that it is preposition actually?

Comment: @Anixx It's a preposition derived from a noun like many other prepositions both in Russian and in English, the noun is "путь" (road), "путём" actually means "by the way of". It's a preposition, not a noun, because it uses such a meaning of the noun "путь" which isn't used when it's really a noun. The preposition "путём" can be substituted by "при помощи" while the noun in the Instr. case "путём" can't be substituted with it, the noun "путь" cannot mean "помощь". Like all Russian prepositions the preposition "путём" can't be used without a following noun, but the homonimous noun and adverb can.

Comment: "при помощи" is also preposition?

Comment: @Anixx, yes, a preposition, "с помощью" is a preposition, too.

Answer (score -4):

"Путем" isn't proposition, this adverb means: all right, sensibly.
Often say: "Все путем", verbatim this means - all right.
http://ozhegov.slovaronline.com/%D0%9F/%D0%9F%D0%A3/28265-PUTEM

Comment: This is only one of all possible meanings. Your answer as it currently stands is misleading.